# Continuous function differentiable almost everywhere, show f' is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and differentiable almost everywhere, show that $f'$ is measurable.

I feel like I should use some sequences, but I don't know how to start.
 Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let:

$$g_n(t) = \frac{f(t + \frac1{n}) - f(t)}{\frac1{n}}$$

Then $(g_n)$ is a sequence of measurable functions which converges pointwise to $f'$ a.e.

Hence $f'$ is (Lebesgue) measurable.

Comment: Thank you! Can you also tell me why exactly $g_n$'s are measurable, please?

Comment: @corkol. composition of continuous functions

Comment: @T. Eskin Thanks, sometimes I'm trying to overcomplicate things ;)